# Status bar not being hidden in Ionic View on iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

In my Ionic v1.2 app I have set the following ([according to the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)):

```
function Run($rootScope, $state, $http) {
  ...
  ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    ionic.Platform.fullScreen(true, true);
  });
}
```

This should make my app fullscreen and show the status bar. Of course, things look fine when previewing in the web browser (using `ionic serve` or `http-server`):

[image]

But when testing in Ionic View, the status bar overlaps with the header:

[image]

Is there some known workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar to achieve this.

Ref: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

And in your app use the below code to hide the status bar,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    StatusBar.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of @Subash answer, you need to set some statusbar configuration in Xcode, but the trick is in your plist file. You need to add property "View controller-based status bar appearance" with value "NO". Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the plugin statusbar:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar
```

And then you can custom your status bar as you want: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/

I would recommend you add these lines into your code, so you still can see the status bar at the top of the screen:

```
if (window.StatusBar) {
  Statusbar.overlaysWebView(true);
  StatusBar.style(1); 
}
```